# How does a prioritization query work (one value is preferred over another if a criteria is met)

Tags: mysql, sql

**[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=24974d0e8641f75f933e29d7caf078cd)**

```
CREATE TABLE Purchasing (
    Campaign VARCHAR(255),
    Event_Type VARCHAR(255),
    Quantity_Offer VARCHAR(255),
    Quantity_Order VARCHAR(255),
    Quantity_Received VARCHAR(255),
    Quantity_Stored VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO Purchasing
(Campaign, Event_Type, Quantity_Offer, Quantity_Order, Quantity_Received, Quantity_Stored)
VALUES 
("C001", "Offered", "300", NULL, NULL, NULL),
("C001", "Ordered", NULL, "350", NULL, NULL),
("C001", "Received", NULL, NULL, "348", NULL),
("C001", "Stored", NULL, NULL, NULL, "345"),

("C002", "Offered", "800", NULL, NULL, NULL),
("C002", "Ordered", NULL, "720", NULL, NULL),
("C002", "Received", NULL, NULL, "730", NULL),
("C002", "Stored", NULL, NULL, NULL, "735"),

("C003", "Offered", "600", NULL, NULL, NULL),
("C003", "Ordered", NULL, "400", NULL, NULL),
("C003", "Received", NULL, NULL, "410", NULL),

("C004", "Offered", "150", NULL, NULL, NULL),
("C004", "Ordered", NULL, "200", NULL, NULL),

("C005", "Offered", "430", NULL, NULL, NULL),
("C005", "Ordered", NULL, "440", NULL, NULL),

("C006", "Offered", "520", NULL, NULL, NULL),
("C006", "Ordered", NULL, "670", NULL, NULL),

("C007", "Offered", "330", NULL, NULL, NULL),
("C008", "Offered", "780", NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

The table displays different `campaigns` and their status within the purchasing process using `event_types`. 
 The process is as the following:

```
Stored > Received > Ordered > Offered
```

---

Based on this structure the result should look like this:

```
Campaign        Event_Type         Quantity
C001              Stored              345
C002              Stored              735
C003              Received            410
C004              Ordered             200
C005              Ordered             440
C006              Ordered             670
C007              Offered             330
C008              Offered             780
```

In order to achieve this I go with the **prioritization query** described in the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60463912/only-display-values-of-latest-available-event-type):

```
select 
campaign, 
event_type,
coalesce(Quantity_Offered, Quantity_Ordered, Quantity_Received, Quantity_Stored) AS Quantity
from Purchasing p
where event_type = (select p2.event_type
                    from Purchasing p2
                    where p2.campaign = p.campaign
                    order by field(p2.event_type, 'Stored', 'Received', 'Ordered', 'Offered')
                    limit 1
                   );
```

This query gives me exactly the result I need. 
However, I am wondering how this query actually works because when I run only this part:

```
select p2.event_type
from Purchasing p2
order by field(p2.event_type, 'Stored', 'Received', 'Ordered', 'Offered')
limit 1;
```

The result is just:

```
event_type
Stored
```

How does the query know which of the `event_type` comes after `stored`?

Comment: see the output of this `select event_type, field(event_type, 'Stored', 'Received', 'Ordered', 'Offered') from Purchasing`, and make sure you know what `coalesce` does do....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=d3aa68abe12c2afc40b8fbfdad10d0e5)**

**Step 1:** 
The `correlated subquery` - in this case `WHERE p2.campaign = p.campaign` - goes through all `campaigns` and identifies all available `event_types` per campaign. 
 Basically, the **inner query** is re-executed for each `campaign`

```
SELECT 
p2.event_type
FROM Purchasing p2
WHERE Campaign ="C003";
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery

**Step 2:** 
Afterwards all available results per `campaign` are ordered by the defined
hierarchy of the `event_type` in the `field` function.

```
SELECT p2.event_type, 
field(event_type, 'Stored', 'Received', 'Ordered', 'Offered') as Position_in_Field
FROM Purchasing p2
ORDER BY 2;
```

https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-field-function.php

**Step 3:** 
Finally, the `LIMIT 1` only leaves the highest available `event_type`
in the result and thus the `WHERE` clause of the **outer query** gets the 
highest `event_type` per `campaign`.

```
SELECT 
p2.event_type
FROM Purchasing p2
WHERE Campaign ="C003"
ORDER BY field(p2.event_type, 'Stored', 'Received', 'Ordered', 'Offered')
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

This line is the key(comment it and check the results):

```
where p2.campaign = p.campaign
```

Your subquery is [correlated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery) . It locates actual Event_Type for every campaign.
When your execute the subquery separately without correlation condition it analyze all Purchasing-table.