# Prioritize one column over another

Tags: mysql, sql

**[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=cfddfcb28009cdd2402a25c33ec8be7f)**

```
CREATE TABLE logistics (
    id int primary key,
    campaign VARCHAR(255),
    quantity_offered VARCHAR(255),
    quantity_ordered VARCHAR(255), 
    quantity_delivered VARCHAR(255),
    quantity_recorded VARCHAR(255),
    quantity_completed VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO logistics
(id, campaign,
quantity_offered, quantity_ordered, quantity_delivered, 
quantity_recorded, quantity_completed
)
VALUES 
("1", "C001", "500", "450", "465", "462", "465"),
("2", "C002", "700", "570", NULL, NULL, NULL),
("3", "C003", "600", "610", "605", "602", NULL),
("4", "C004", "300", NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
("5", "C005", "400", "425", NULL, NULL, NULL),
("6", "C006", "900", "870", "868", NULL, NULL),
("7", "C007", "350", "360", "372", "375", "390"),
("8", "C008", "250", "290", NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

In the table above I have different `campaigns` with their corresponding `quantities`. 
The `quantities` are filled in different `columns`.

---

Now, I want to get the **latest available quantity** for each `campaign` based on the following hierarchy:

```
quantity_completed > quantity_recorded > quantity_delivered > quantity_ordered > quantity_offered
```

The result should look like this:

```
Campaign      Quantity
C001            465
C002            570
C003            602
C004            300
C005            425
C006            870
C007            390
C008            290
```

What query do I need to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `coalesce()`:

```
select campaign, coalesce(quantity_completed, quantity_recorded, quantity_delivered, quantity_ordered, quantity_offered) as quantity
from logistics;
```

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=76fcbc871b902798c4ab86c552e74da8

Comment: I assume - in contrast to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60463912/only-display-values-of-latest-available-event-type - I do not need a correlated subquery here since each campaign only appears once and all quantities are defined in one row.

Comment: @Michi . . . Yes, the values are all in one row.  That said, I'm not sure why you accepted the more complicated answer on the other question, but that is up to you.